# Looking for a function $f(x)$ and a point $x=a$ such that $f(a)$ is easy to calculate but $f(a + h)$ is not, for $h$ near zero.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When discussing linearization, James Stewart mentions that it may be easy to calculate $f(a)$ but difficult or impossible to calculate $f(x)$ near $a$.  He doesn't give an example and that makes us very curious.  Is there a well-known, famous case that you could you present?

Comment: Just about any non-polynomial function.  $\sin (x)$ for instance, or $10^{-x}$.

Comment: How about $f(x) = ln(x)$, with $a=1$?

Comment: Square roots are popular toy examples. E.g. approximating $\sqrt{1.2}$ using $1.1^2 = 1.21$.